# Right Table Row to Go Below Left Row

Tags: html

I want td on the right (pagination buttons) to go Below left td (buttons) when there isn't enough space.( small screens).

Is it doable ?

```
<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" width="100%" style="margin-bottom:3px">
<tr valign="bottom">
        <td class="smallfont"> "Buttons on Left </td>

    <td align="$stylevar[right]"> "Page navigation Buttons on Right </td>

</tr>
</table>
```

Comment: draw an example GUI for us to get the idea what exactly you want. ^_^.. Use paint :P

Comment: I want something like this:  http://jsfiddle.net/isherwood/frk7jbvu/3/  blue box goes under other boxes when page is minimised. I tried but couldn't get the syntax right.

Answer (score 0):

Add an Extra column for the table and hide for desktop.while going to mobile ,hide the fist column and show the third column

```css
 .hide-for-desktop{
    display:none;
 }
 
 .@media screen and (max-width: 500px) {
     
     table td{
        display:block;
        width:100%;
     }
     
     .hide-for-desktop{
        display:block
     }
     
     .hide-for-mobile{
         display:none !important;
     }
     
 }
```

```html
<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" width="100%" style="margin-bottom:3px">
    <tr valign="bottom">
        <td class="smallfont hide-for-mobile"> "Buttons on Left </td>
        <td align="$stylevar[right]"> "Page navigation Buttons on Right </td>
      <td  class="smallfont hide-for-desktop"> "Buttons on Left </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```